# Notifier about visible ISS passes and/or Iridium flares for Ubuntu PC

Tags: software, artificial-satellite

I am trying to find application that would be capable of notifying me about 
[visible ISS pases](http://spotthestation.nasa.gov/) for specified location and/or [visible Iridium flares](http://heavens-above.com/IridiumFlares.aspx) for specified location.

This software must be capable of running on Ubuntu.

I strongly prefer active open-source projects.

I know that there are multiple mobile apps but I want something that may run on Linux PC.

To avoid "this is subjective" - I will be happy about any software fulfilling this requirements and criteria are not subjective.

Comment: Comment only as I don't have any precise information - there is "ISS Above" which is Linux. It's Raspberry Pi-specific software I believe, but if you can get the source code it might be worth having a look at.

Comment: @Andy - it seems to be 148$ for software on Raspberry Pi http://www.issabove.com/what-is-it/ or source-code only for 30$ http://issabove.com/downloads/iss-above-hd-for-pi-2/

Comment: Ah that's a pity (I thought it was open source). I just noticed the Space Exploration stackexchange has a few questions about sat tracking (though at least some are for Windows). For example: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2355/satellite-tracking-software

Comment: I assume https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_satellite_pass_predictors#Linux and https://celestrak.com/software/satellite/sat-trak.asp were unhelpful?

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that I wrote for my personal purposes.

Fetches iridium flare details based on your heavens-above credentials and displays a notification in Ubuntu.

[Github](https://github.com/astronomersiva/satellite-passes-notifier)

I had one for ISS passes as well. Will find it and push it to the repo soon.

Comment: It is promising but at this moment it has some problems (I opened PRs for some and issues for other - see https://github.com/astronomersiva/satellite-passes-notifier/pulse)

Comment: are you planning to address mentioned issues (see https://github.com/astronomersiva/satellite-passes-notifier/issues)? Especially lack of license, as it strongly discourages from making improvements - I would not be able to fully use my own improvements.